# Automatic adjustment of ingredients according to specific nutritional requirements

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming

Considering you have a group of ingredients:
oat, rice, nuts, etc.
Each ingredient has specific nutritional values.

> 100 grams of oat -> fat = 20, protein = 30, carbs = 40

What approach should I use to automatically calculate the ingredients and quantities required to obtain a target mix with specific nutritional values?

> fat = 142, protein = 392, carbs = 34

The programming language is not important; I am just curious about the method.

Comment: There is no way to achieve that goal for every given values. For example: 100 grams of oat -> 50 fat and 50 protein. You want mix = 100 fat, and 120 protein. You can't reach that mix.

Comment: those are just example quantities...